# Where can i find complete list of features for es5, es6, and es7?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I want to stay on top of features I have missed and the ones that are coming out. I'd like comprehensive list so then i can go and search what i need to search.

Comment: You're looking for the specification.

Comment: Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and the [specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/)

Comment: https://github.com/tc39/proposals if you want to follow what's coming the next version(s).

Comment: @SLaks i dont want specification. It'd take one college semester just to go through that. Mdn is kinda 50/50. Sometimes very thorough, sometimes get updated like last on internet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kangax's compatibility tables also double as a comprehensive list of the features that were added in each specification: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: are those all the features, look pretty maintained

Comment: @MuhammadUmer Yes, as far as I know. Since its job is to measure browsers' adherence to all the new features in the spec, it should probably list all the new features in the spec. Also, kangax's tables have a good reputation for accuracy and they are open source: https://github.com/kangax/compat-table

Comment: Please keep in mind that questions like this one are off-topic.